# Flutter - Navigating to specific screen and popping everything above it

Tags: flutter, navigation, material-design

hello there i have this classes

ServicesIndex
ServicesCreate
ServicesEdit

what i want to do is on click of button in either Create or Edit i want to  pop all alerts and pages and push replacement to ServicesIndex
what should i do exactly ?

the button which will be clicked in Services Create and Edit

```
showSuccessMessage(context) {
  var responsivenessController = ResponsivenessController(context);
  Alert(
    context: context,
    type: AlertType.success,
    style: AlertStyle(titleStyle: Theme
        .of(context)
        .textTheme
        .bodyText1
        , descStyle: Theme
            .of(context)
            .textTheme
            .bodyText1),
    title: translator.currentLanguage == 'ar' ? 'تم الحفظ'
        : 'Stored Successfully',
    desc: translator.currentLanguage == 'ar' ? 'تمت عملية الحفظ بنجاح'
        : 'Information Stored Successfully',
    buttons: [
      DialogButton(
          child: Text(
            translator.currentLanguage == 'ar' ?
            "المتابعة"
                : 'OK',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: responsivenessController.bodyFont),
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          }

      )
    ],
  ).show();
}
```

its all in on pressed event what code do you suggest  ?

about the stack of elements its

```
Index 
  ---Create
    ---SuccessMessage
  ---Edit
    ---SuccessMessage
```

so the action should pop 2 times and push replacement
i can of course hard code like this

```
          onPressed: () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
        Navigator.pop(context);
        Navigator.pop(context);
        Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (BuildContext context) => className
        ));
      }
```

but i want something more flexible like just pass the Class name and it will return to it while popping everything before it

Note : Named Routes will not work because every page requires some parameters that will be passed later in the process i can't fetch them all in main.dart i will cause slow performance

Comment: checkout popUntil https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/popUntil.html.

Comment: the problem is as mentioned in my Note  I can't use named routes all the time because i have information will only be available at specific time in the future but thanks for the reminder ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know how many pop you need to call then simply use `popUntil` with a `counter`.

**Code**

```dart
// In this case we want to pop 4 times
void onPressed() {
   int count = 0;
   Navigator.popUntil(context, (route) => count++ == 4);
}
```

Comment: well actually this is a good approach thank you very much